# Download image using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm working on an phonegap app for iphone, But, now i'm in trouble to find a way do download images from the server to the iphone gallery...

I have these small code that gets the file content:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open('GET',"http://site.com/imagefile.jpg", false);   
req.send();
```

But, I dont know how to force to save it.
If not possible this way, I can also get the image file codeded into base64... I dont think if this will help something.

Could you please, give me some explanation?

I googled a lot, but I didnt find samples...

Comment: So you want to download the image and then save it into the iPhone photos folder?

Comment: yes... But i didnt find a way to do this yet. I only need to figure out this, to finish my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save to iphone photo's folder with Phonegap (without writing an extension at least).  So you can't really save the photo's to a file (again without an extension), the only real way to save photos in a cross-platform (and thus phonegap html & Javascript way) way is to save them to a local sqlite database.  See Jesse MacFayden's article on doing this on the [Phonegap site](http://www.phonegap.com/2009/09/24/image-caching-with-the-html5-canvas/).   Jesse leaves the actual saving of the image to database and loading it as a work for the reader, but if you have problems with that I just wrote an answer on how to use the [database in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538313/what-are-the-requirements-for-phonegap-database-application-for-iphone/4540419#4540419) just this morning.