# What are the requirements for PhoneGap database application for IPhone?

Tags: iphone, database, cordova

I would like to create a simple application accessing a database.

Does **PhoneGap** has this feature in its framework?

Which database technology does it use? MySQL? Any database?

What are the requirements for developing a PhoneGap database application for IPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database (the Sqlite database) is baked right into Webkit (and Safari), though you do get some added functionality from Phonegap (the ability to [pre-populate a Database](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/ca6c85f7d6c3976c)).  But you can just develop in HTML5 and Javascript to start.  Apple provides a reference for [Client Side storage](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256).  If you are looking for some sample code to play with, here is a little testbed I came up with to play with [HTML5 databases](https://github.com/kriserickson/HTML5-Database-Testbed).  Note: when I say HTML5 databases, I mean Webkit as Mozilla is [skeptical about adding an SQL database to HTML5 at all](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/beyond-html5-database-apis-and-the-road-to-indexeddb/).

Answer (score 1):

Though PhoneGap recommends using the websql as a means of data storage, it should be mentioned (but its not) that the responses from queries are not instantaneously returned. This is just simply a limitation of using Phonegap. Here is a function I've used to tie a websql database query with a particular action.

http://snipplr.com/view/50724/query-local-database-with-targeted-callback-and-custom-arguements/

For smaller chunks of data that you want to store on the device you can use LocalStorage. 
I've found it reasonable to use JSON.stringify to convert a simple object into a string to be stored in LocalStorage. And upon retrieval JSON.parse it. Here is another snippet to assist in using this method.

http://snipplr.com/view/54570/local-storage-html5-wrapper/