# How can binary files be requested from GreaseMonkey userscripts?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, greasemonkey, binary-data

**Backstory**

I wrote a specialized image inliner script that is intended to be used with both GreaseMonkey and Google Chrome.  It is supposed to download PNG files and store them in `data:` urls in image `src` attributes.  This may sound ridiculous, but a certain website sets `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` for images, and I don't want the «Save As» dialog to pop up every time.

**The actual question**

The script fetches data with an `XMLHttpRequest`, encodes it into base64 and stores it in a proper place.  So far, good.  But it only works when I run it through both Firebug and Chrome dev consoles, and does not when I use it as a proper userscript.  As far as I understand, this is because Greasemonkey scripts cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` objects directly and should rely on calls to `GM_xmlhttpRequest` instead.  However, I cannot set `responseType` to `"blob"` or `"arraybuffer"` that way, and the `binary` parameter seems to only work for sending data through POST requests.  I only get Unicode strings.

Just in case, the images are served from the same domain as the page that links to them.  I believe it satisfies the «same origin» thingy.

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest here are the GM_xmlhttpRequest docs.

Is there a way to fetch an `arraybuffer` from within a Greasemonkey userscript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading an image using XMLHttpRequest in a userscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778863/downloading-an-image-using-xmlhttprequest-in-a-userscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it ***is*** same-domain, then you can use `XMLHttpRequest`, with no problems.  The only reason to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` (which currently has a crippled subset of functionality) is if the images/files are cross domain.

For **same-domain**, you can use XHR2 as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781262/331508).

For **cross-domain**, you must: use `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, override the mime-type, and use a custom encoder algorithm.  Again, this is all shown in [that same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781262/331508).

---

*However,* it sounds like you are just trying to make it easier to download images?  If that is so, then you might be better off just using the excellent [DownThemAll extension](http://www.downthemall.net/).

Comment: Thanks!  Chrome does not allow setting `responseType` for synchronous requests (`open(,,false)`) though, and asynchronous requests don't work for some reason (it never calls `onload`), but it works in Greasemonkey.

Comment: I am trying to inline images into the page on a certain website, so using an extension just for the one site is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

> overrideMimeType String (Compatibility: 0.6.8+) Optional. A MIME type
>   to specify with the request (E.G. "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1").

You can set this to `plain/text; charset=x-user-defined` (the type doesn't matter but the charset does), bitwise AND through the response string and add the values to a typed array and get the buffer:

```
var text = xhr.responseText,
    len = text.length,
    arr = new Uint8Array(len),
    i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        arr[i] = text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    }

    arr.buffer //The arraybuffer
```

Note: this is for raw binary responses, not base64.